# Using ScaLAPACK routine from MPI C program

Tags: mpi

I currently have an MPI program written in C and I want to use a routine from ScaLAPACK.
I'm working on a parallel version of LDA, and one step is inverting a matrix.
I found a routine in ScaLAPACK that solves this pdgetri.f (it's written in fortran, I'm not sure that a c routine exists), but I'm not sure how to configure it to work. I'm using Windows and an Intel Dual Core Laptop. The purpose is more didactic than for performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SCALAPACK relies on [BLACS](http://www.netlib.org/blacs/) to provide abstraction to whatever message passing system is in use. If you have an existing MPI communicator established in your code, you can use [blacs_gridmap](http://www.netlib.org/blacs/BLACS/QRef.html#BLACS_GRIDMAP) to initialise a BLACS context which is mapped onto your communicator. That context can then be used to create SCALAPACK distributed arrays and those arrays then passed to SCALPACK routines which will then operate on them.

How you tackle the C-Fortran interfacing problem will depend a lot on what compiler(s) you are using. If you have a "modern" compiler which supports Fortran 2003 features, you can use the C interoperability language features to write an interface wrapper for the functions you need, and then call them directly. On UNIX/LINUX style systems, F2C style interfacing was the defacto way to call Fortran from C, although some of the details where usually compiler specific. I don't use Windows at all, so I can really help you if you can't use Fortran 2003 interoperability.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I understand that the key is interoperation between C and Fortran. I'll work on this. I would switch to Linux in one second, but just the thought of configuring MPI there also is scarry :)

Comment: @talonmies: it seems you knew about scalapack all along, and could have told me about it two days ago...  but, is there not some standard wrapper for C that we can use, instead of re-inventing the Fortran/C interface each time?

Comment: @HughPerkins: Seriously? You asked an incredibly general, naive question about fast Cholesky decomposition with C++ and MPI, with a very unrealistic performance goal, and now you want to chide me for not providing an answer about a very portable, generic library, not very performant *FORTRAN* library? Good luck with that....

Comment: @talonmies: you say that scalapack is not very performant.  Do you know of a better library for use with C and MPI?

Comment: @HughPerkins: Take that remark *in the context of a small Cholesky factorisation*, which is what you are really asling about. Most parallel distributed Cholesky codes are right looking, and the FLOPs are in a distributed symmetric rank k update - and right at the bottom of that is gemm. So start from the beginning: go and find yourself an architecturally optimal gemm and benchmark it (both size and cores). Use those results to determine the optimal structure of a pdsyrk. The benchmark that. That is your *upper* performance bound for a Cholesky factorisation.

Comment: @talonmies: ok, so after googling gemm and pdsyrk, those are both BLAS names, so it seems that you are implicitly stating that scalapack is the way to go?  Do you have any ballpark figures for the scalability of scalapack for cholesky?  I've found a really old scalapack tutorial which shows grudging scalability up to about 12 cores or so.  Beyond 12 cores, does it start hitting theoretical limits, connected to either the gemm or the pdsyrk?

Comment: @HughPerkins: No I am not telling you to use anything, implicitly or otherwise. I am trying to get you to understand how to obtain a ballpark upper bound performance estimate for a distributed memory Cholesky factorisation. Until you know what that is, how can you possible judge what is or is not performant/scalable *on your target cluster*? These are questions only you can answer by benchmarking yourself. Once you know that, you can adjust your performance aims accordindly. There is little point in continuing this dicussion, I am afraid. I won't be replying further.